# Module ''*'' has no exported member 'app'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

We are developing an open source app on ionic 2 platform, someone added Firebase to the project and I made pull request and now when I try to run the app I get this error. It is probably related to some of Firebase dependencies or packages. How can I fix this?

Pretty much every line related to Firebase gives this error. For instance:

```
export declare function _getAuthBackend(app: firebase.app.App): FirebaseSdkAuthBackend;
```

here is the code:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
export declare abstract class AuthBackend {
    abstract authWithCustomToken(token: string): Promise<FirebaseAuthState>;
    abstract authAnonymously(options?: any): Promise<FirebaseAuthState>;
    abstract authWithPassword(credentials: EmailPasswordCredentials): Promise<FirebaseAuthState>;
    abstract authWithOAuthPopup(provider: AuthProviders, options?: any): Promise<firebase.auth.UserCredential>;
    abstract authWithOAuthRedirect(provider: AuthProviders, options?: any): Promise<void>;
    abstract authWithOAuthToken(credentialsObj: firebase.auth.AuthCredential, options?: any): Promise<FirebaseAuthState>;
    abstract onAuth(): Observable<FirebaseAuthState>;
    abstract getAuth(): FirebaseAuthState;
    abstract unauth(): Promise<void>;
    abstract createUser(credentials: EmailPasswordCredentials): Promise<FirebaseAuthState>;
    abstract getRedirectResult(): Observable<firebase.auth.UserCredential>;
}
export declare enum AuthProviders {
    Github = 0,
    Twitter = 1,
    Facebook = 2,
    Google = 3,
    Password = 4,
    Anonymous = 5,
    Custom = 6,
}
export declare enum AuthMethods {
    Popup = 0,
    Redirect = 1,
    Anonymous = 2,
    Password = 3,
    OAuthToken = 4,
    CustomToken = 5,
}
export interface AuthConfiguration {
    method?: AuthMethods;
    provider?: AuthProviders;
    scope?: string[];
}
export interface FirebaseAuthState {
    uid: string;
    provider: AuthProviders;
    auth: firebase.User;
    expires?: number;
    github?: firebase.UserInfo;
    google?: firebase.UserInfo;
    twitter?: firebase.UserInfo;
    facebook?: firebase.UserInfo;
    anonymous?: boolean;
}
export declare function authDataToAuthState(authData: firebase.User, providerData?: firebase.UserInfo): FirebaseAuthState;
export declare function stripProviderId(providerId: string): string;
export interface EmailPasswordCredentials {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}
```

Comment: You need to show more code about your component?

Comment: @Sampath it's node module code anyway but I added

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the following configuration step may be missing.

1. add `firebase` to types array in `tsconfig`
2. import in the module

   ```
   import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';    
   @NgModule({
     declarations: [...],
     imports: [
       ...,
       AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
     ],
   ...
   ```

3.You may need to run

```
typings install
```

Note:-

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "<your-key>",
  authDomain: "<your-project-authdomain>",
  databaseURL: "<your-database-URL>",
  storageBucket: "<your-storage-bucket>"
}
```